# Why does neo4j always has a single node?

Tags: neo4j

The below code prints `id: 0`. Why is there a node in empty graph db?

```
GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_LOCATION);
GlobalGraphOperations graphOperations = GlobalGraphOperations.at(db);
System.out.println("id: "+graphOperations.getAllNodes().iterator().next().getId());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, neo4j is created with what they call a [Reference Node](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#getReferenceNode%28%29) which is Node 0. You can delete this without consequence, and I believe that it may be phased out in Future releases, as you can see from the documentation on it that they are deprecating the call to retrieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Its never really an empty graph db, there is a graph with one node - the reference node with id 0. Neo4j always has this node created by default.

Also refer : 
[should everything connect with node 0 in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186803/should-everything-connect-with-node-0-in-neo4j)